Safety from quantum attacks
I recently read that China was able to use quantum computer for cracking military grade encryption.
https://thequantuminsider.com/2024/10/11/chinese-scientists-report-using-quantum-computer-to-hack-military-grade-encryption/
The article does admit that the present quantum capability is still in its infancy to affect banks and other services.
But let's say that they are able to advance quantum computing to the extent that they can crack into banks and military. How safe is today's blockchain from such future quantum developments?
What can be done to secure blockchain from such extreme situations?

Also Chinese researchers' claimed quantum encryption crack looks unlikely
